# How to switch off / restart Mobile using Java ME Code

Tags: java-me

I want to know is there any API in Java ME, using which I can Switch Off or Restart the Mobile Phone ?

Comment: Why on earth would you like to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no specific API for this.  However several handsets have undocumented J2ME bugs which will cause the phone to reboot, that you could utilise for this purpose!

Comment: Funkybro can you suggest some .??