# Switch OFF Mobile Phone through J2ME Midlet

Tags: java-me, symbian, nokia, midlet, symbian3

I want to Switch OFF my Phone through code via a button click. any idea how to do it in J2ME .?

thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to switch off / restart Mobile using Java ME Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960924/how-to-switch-off-restart-mobile-using-java-me-code)

Answer (score 3):

Unofrtunately there is no MIDlet-Permission to allow you to do that.
(not really an answer, but I'm too newbie on StackOverflow to be allowed comments)